# When initialzing a variable of an interface type, what happens to the non-interface methods belonging to the class in the initialization statement?

Tags: java, interface

When .getClass() is called on myMap and myTreemap, "class java.util.LinkedHashMap" and "class java.util.TreeMap" are returned. Despite the matching return types, myMap can only use the methods in the map interface. I've heard that this eases programming by allowing programmers to change the implementation type easily. But - what good is changing the implementation type if I (seemingly) can only access the methods in the interface?

Also - myMap are myTreeMap are sorted according to their class type but again, what about the methods of the class type?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Freq {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String a : args) {
        Integer freq = m.get(a);
        m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
    }

    System.out.println(m.size() + " distinct words:");
    System.out.println(m);

    System.out.println();

    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(m);       
    System.out.println("map: " + myMap.getClass());
    //output is "map: class java.util.LinkedHashMap"
    //but, only the methods in the myMap interface can be accessed.

    System.out.println(myMap.toString());
    //output in order of appearance like a LinkedHashMap should.


    TreeMap<String, Integer> myTreemap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(m);
    System.out.println("treemap: " + myTreemap.getClass());
    //output is "treemap: class java.util.TreeMap"
    //methods in the Map interface and myTreemap can be accessed.

    System.out.println(myTreemap.toString());
    //output in in alphabetical order like a treemap should.

    } 
}
```

Comment: what is your specific question? if you want to use treemap proper methods then `TreeMap mymap = new TreeMap()` .. it said `program to an interface not an implementation` for designing to change and follows contracts, the good is that they are doing the same but in different way, may complexity changes between implementations

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are a great feature. Think about it -- lets say you want to implement an algorithm that uses a hashMap. Previously in the code, the user chose a hash map implementation that was optimized in algorithms ran earlier. If you didn't have an interface,(rather, if the concept of interfaces didn't exist at all...or a set of function pointers didn't exist at all ), you would have to create the new algorithm that you want to implement for each implementation of the hash map. That's a lot of redundant code, and it's not very readable.

You don't really lose access to the underlying methods. However, if you want to access the underlying TreeMap and its methods...you will have to cast it to a tree map from a map.

```
@suppressedwarnings
TreeMap treeMap = null;    
if(myMap instanceof TreeMap){
    treeMap = (TreeMap)myMap;
}
if(treeMap == null){
     return;
     //If it wasn't the correct type, then it could not safely be cast.
}
//Now, do treeMap stuff
treeMap.treeMapOnlyMethod();
```

Using instanceof is usually an indicator of poor design -- instead, polymorphism should be used.

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard that this eases programming by allowing programmers to change the implementation type easily.

Correct.

> But - what good is changing the implementation type if I (seemingly) can only access the methods in the interface?

You can get e.g. Tree or Hash variants using the same API, the one published by the interface, while only changing the code at one place. If you were allowed to use the class's non-interface methods you wouldn't get that benefit: you would have to change all those calls too.

> Also - myMap are myTreeMap are sorted according to their class type but again, what about the methods of the class type?

I don't understand the question. What about them?

Comment: LinkedHashMap and Treemap have constructors that order their keys differently. I'm thinking that when a variable (myMap) of an interface type is initialized to either implementation, the order of myMap's keys are ordered by the initializer's constructor. Am I getting that right? If I declare, List list=new TreeMap() what other things is "list" getting from Treemap (if anything at all)?

Comment: `list` isn't 'getting' anything. `list` *is* a `TreeMap`. Period.

Comment: @user465001 `List list = new TreeMap()` doesn't compile because `TreeMap` does not implement the `List` interface. Maybe if you explain in another way your misunderstanding I may be able to help you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I meant Map myMap = new TreeMap. I was trying to find out what other characteristics myMap would get from TreeMap. Would the same go for List myList = new ArrayList? What characteristics of ArrayList would myList get? How could I find out these characteristics ahead of time?

Comment: @EJP - EJP, I've corrected my List list = new Treemap above. Could you explain this a little more?: "You can get e.g. Tree or Hash variants using the same API, the one published by the interface, while only changing the code at one place."

Comment: @user465001 It's not about characteristics, but about methods you can call. For example, if `TreeMap` has a different order of iteration than `LinkedHashMap`, these differences will remain when you access the maps through an interface, because in both cases you call the same methods: `keySet().iterator()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Treemap will order keys in alphabetical order and, LinkedHashMap will order keys in the order they appeared. I believe that it is their blank constructors that set the order. I'm thinking of the order as a characteristic. Would that be correct? If I was choosing an implementation of Map to initialize myMap to, I guess part of my decision could include which implementation has a more efficient version of one of the interface's methods as well as characteristics supplied by the constructor?

Comment: @user465001 No, constructor is not the one which sets the order: it is the implementation of the class itself. Well, except for `LinkedHashMap`, where you do actually have two, but very similar choices, both easily covered by the same implementation code. You just have to separate in your mind the notion of abstract API, which is defined by the interface, and the specific characteristics of each implementation. Each implementation adheres strictly to the rules defined for the interface methods, but each one does something different regarding those characteristics which *aren't* specified.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Could you explain further what you mean by `"No, constructor is not the one which sets the order: it is the implementation of the class itself."`? If the class was Treemap, would the `comparator()` method usages fall under "the implementation of the class itself"? Additionally, each implementation of the Map interface may have fields. For example, Hashmap has `static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;` So if `Map myNewmap = new HashMap()`, won't myNewMap also have a initial capacity of `16`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I'm also guessing that TreeMap uses Comparator and Comparable to help start its sorting. Do these interfaces fall under `"the implementation of the class itself"`? Does `"the implementation of the class itself"` mean the combinations of methods, fields, etc in the class?

Comment: @user465001 The implementation of the class is the code written inside `class { ... }` So yes, it's methods, fields, and everything else. I think I see what you meant now by the "choice of constructor", you meant the choice between `new HashMap()` and `new TreeMap()`. But it's primarily the choice of *class* and only secondarily choice of constructor: `HashMap` is choice of class and `()` is choice of constructor with no arguments. When we apply this clarification, I think you've got it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Thanks, Marko. And one last thing - `Hashmap` has a field `static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;` If I use `Map myNewmap = new HashMap()`, won't `myNewMap` also have a initial capacity of `16`?

Comment: @user465001 Yes, it will, you can inspect the constructor code on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.%3Cinit%3E%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You will understand the point of interface much better if you look at an example with method parameters:

```
boolean validateMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
  return map.get("x") != null && map.get("y") != null;
}
```

Observe that this method doesn't care which exactly map you passed in: it will work equally well with any type. That's the beauty of polymorphism.